# Bulk Insert Multiple (More than 1000 XML file) XML files with SSIS 2008 R2

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, ssis, business-intelligence

I have below one of XML files that i need to bulk insert them into SQL server, i have more than 1000 XML and i want to use SSIS for this purpose, any ideas please?
all XML having the same attribute with different data content.

```
    <?xml version = "1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" standalone="yes"?>
<VFPData>
    <cr_attributes>
        <headerexpression>1-108-201403-18-A01276</headerexpression>
        <timesheetfield>cc2</timesheetfield>
        <sessioninstance>d425d70e-7baf-4f6f-8302-a327b7ded320</sessioninstance>
        <originvalue/>
        <pagenum>1</pagenum>
        <pageaddress>81.1865.11.78</pageaddress>
        <fieldid>860002635</fieldid>
        <fieldname>TS6CCode2</fieldname>
        <interpretaccuracy>100</interpretaccuracy>
        <timestamp>4/1/2014 3:53:28 PM</timestamp>
        <pen>AJX-AA7-D98-UX</pen>
        <validationlink/>
        <cfieldvalue>5300330</cfieldvalue>
        <crowkey>18-A01276</crowkey>
        <calias>PayCard</calias>
        <lvaluechanged>true</lvaluechanged>
    </cr_attributes>
    <cr_attributes>
        <headerexpression>1-108-201403-18-A01276</headerexpression>
        <timesheetfield>cc2_sub</timesheetfield>
        <sessioninstance>d425d70e-7baf-4f6f-8302-a327b7ded320</sessioninstance>
        <originvalue/>
        <pagenum>1</pagenum>
        <pageaddress>81.1865.11.78</pageaddress>
        <fieldid>860002642</fieldid>
        <fieldname>TS6SCode2</fieldname>
        <interpretaccuracy>100</interpretaccuracy>
        <timestamp>4/1/2014 3:53:32 PM</timestamp>
        <pen>AJX-AA7-D98-UX</pen>
        <validationlink/>
        <cfieldvalue>000002</cfieldvalue>
        <crowkey>18-A01276</crowkey>
        <calias>PayCard</calias>
        <lvaluechanged>true</lvaluechanged>
    </cr_attributes>
    <cr_attributes>
        <headerexpression>1-108-201403-18-A01276</headerexpression>
        <timesheetfield>hr_cc2</timesheetfield>
        <sessioninstance>d425d70e-7baf-4f6f-8302-a327b7ded320</sessioninstance>
        <originvalue>.0</originvalue>
        <pagenum>1</pagenum>
        <pageaddress>81.1865.11.78</pageaddress>
        <fieldid>860002658</fieldid>
        <fieldname>TS6HRCC21</fieldname>
        <interpretaccuracy>100</interpretaccuracy>
        <timestamp>4/1/2014 3:53:20 PM</timestamp>
        <pen>AJX-AA7-D98-UX</pen>
        <validationlink/>
        <cfieldvalue>08</cfieldvalue>
        <crowkey>T24112-FAROOQ AHMAD</crowkey>
        <calias>PayIn</calias>
        <lvaluechanged>true</lvaluechanged>
    </cr_attributes>
</VFPData>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Components required:

To iterate through 1000 xml file - Use Foreach loop container

To read each xml file - Use XML Source component

To Load xml into database - Use OLE DB Destination component

To Change xml file path dynamically - Use expression and variable.

While iterating through each XML file, the XML Source connection needs to be changed each time. So to make this dynamic, you need to create variable to store XML file-path(get from Foreach loop container),and set this variable to XML Source connection manager property.

Below resources will provide you step by step walk-through to understand above component.

[Working with Variables](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/working-with-variables-in-sql-server-integration-services/)

[SSIS Expressions Basics](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DevinKnight/ssis/79/ssis-expressions-basics)

[Working with Property Expressions](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/working-with-property-expressions-in-sql-server-integration-services/)

Step 1 [SSIS BASICS: Introducing the Foreach Loop Container](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-introducing-the-foreach-loop-container/)

Step 2 [MSDN - XML Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140277.aspx)

Step 3 [Loading XML Using SSIS](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2011/04/07/loading-xml-using-ssis/)

Step 4 [Loading multiple XML file from  the file system into a SQL Server table using SSIS.](http://blog.jontav.com/post/7612017013/import-xml-into-sql-server-using-ssis)

Since you are handling 1000 xml files with same schema but varying data length range, so there might be changes that the auto generated schema/XSD by SSIS won't support data content(length and type), you need to tweak auto generated XSD to cover of data-type and data length. You can find guideline in [this thread](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3141/importing-xml-documents-using-sql-server-integration-services/) (last part of article) on how to manually change XSD.

Comment: thanks for your help, can you be specific on how to use the foreach loop container in more points if possible?

Comment: Basically configure foerach loop to retrieve all those XML files from folder.So it's a collection of XML file paths. Then drop data flow task inside foreach container. Then put your logic to upload the XML to database in control flow of DFT. Make source connection property dynamic by using variable so that each time foreach loop iterate through collection of file paths then it should new pass file path to source connection manager each time.

Comment: i didn't get  you for the last thing "Make source connection property dynamic by using variable so that each time foreach loop iterate through collection of file paths then it should new pass file path to source connection manager each time" i already created for each container and i have several paths already also created variables, but the thing after its reading all the XML with the same schema, it still looping and not inserting any rows in the data, how i can let the job exit the conatier once there is no file to insert them in the db @Vikramsinh Shinde